# karate plugin for vsCode not showing syntax highlighting correctly

Tags: karate

When using karate.jsonPath for testing assertions, I am seeing that the syntax coloring is getting misaligned.  Is this something I have coded incorrectly (although my tests are working as expected) or is this possibly a bug in the syntax highlighting of the plugin itself?

You can see in the image that everything starts after the `* def newPassword = karate.jsonPath(response, "$.accessPoints[?(@.id == '" + firstAccessPointID + "')].password" )[0]`, second def line and never seems to recover to the desired, previous, syntax coloring.  The first def line has an intentional double quote at the end to show that one of them within the statement itself appears to not be recognized
syntax coloring in vsCode.  I have tried using other theme plugins, but the issue appears to remain, just behind a different theme.
[image: syntax coloring misalignment]

Unsure if there is a separate tag for the plugins versus karate directly so sorry if this is in the wrong area

Comment: opened an issue to track this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-vscode-extension/issues/11