# karate plugin for vsCode not showing syntax highlighting correctly - take 2

Tags: karate

Previous issue - [karate plugin for vsCode not showing syntax highlighting correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75891705/karate-plugin-for-vscode-not-showing-syntax-highlighting-correctly?noredirect=1#comment133867435_75891705)

We found another syntax highlighting issue:

When adding a parameter option in an outline, the code after the <> is no longer highlighted.
[image: syntax highlight issue]

Comment: you could consider logging an issue. but `<>` is not recommended, and since these are first class variables, use them directly or as `$(embeddedExpressions)`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-intellij-plugin/issues/24 (this link is for intellij issues)

Comment: Since this is an outline, I thought <> were required to identify the fields within the Examples: section.  After review, I see that is not the case, however, when changing the variable reference to $(url), I get this error - `org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "$" is not defined`.  When changing the variable reference to '#(url)', the variable is evaluated as `...v1/safe-browsing/check-url?url=%23%28url%29` rather than the value from the outline table.

Comment: I also tried to define the variable first `* def testUrl = $(url)` but recieve the this error - `no such variable: (url` or as `* def testUrl = '#(url)'` which results in the same `/v1/safe-browsing/check-url?url=%23%28url%29,` evaluation

Comment: After more manipulation, I found that the 's in the outline data caused the issue, so I removed them for the url column and changed the variable reference to `And param url = '<sampleUrl>'`.  NOTE:  I did not add quotes around the url reference in the match test.  Everything appears to be working now after this nuance change.